# Browser S3 upload: File validation or preview

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, upload, fine-uploader, aws-sdk-js

We need to create a single page app that will allow uploading huge CSV files (e.g. 4 GB) to S3.

Some basic CSV validation should be in place, at least for the first N lines of the file.

If there are errors in the file we would abort the upload and show the validation error to the user.

I've opened issues in some major libraries however perhaps there is a better way?

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/2032

https://github.com/cubiclesoft/jquery-fancyfileuploader/issues/5

https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/issues/2004

https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/issues/409#issuecomment-386207199